# How to add a newline in Vuetify v-tooltip

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I have been vuetify's `<v-tooltip>` and I don't find any attributes in their API so I could either use `\n` or `<br />` to create a newline inside the tooltip template.

Exemple :

```
    <v-tooltip>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn>
          button
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>First line \n second line</span>
    </v-tooltip>
```

This will still display

```
First line second line
```

instead of

```
First line 
second line
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert p tags instead of spans, this will separate on to two lines.

Added mb-0 to remove excess spacing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              dark
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
              Button
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <p>Tooltip</p>
          <p class="mb-0">Tooltip2</p>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just insert `<br />` and `v-html` into your tooltip text and the text will appear in a new line.

Example:

```
<v-tooltip top transition="fade-transition" open-delay="500">
   <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      ...
   </template>
   <span v-html="getTextWithNewlines"></span>
</v-tooltip>
```

`getTextWithNewlines` is a function which returns text with newlines... (`<br />`).