How to show v-tooltip content with multiple lines
It seems easy but I couldn't get it to show multiple lines. Is it possible to show using the content?
Here is part of the template from a vue.js component:
Vue.component('label-provider-item',
    {
        props: ['item'],
        template:
            '<div v-if="item && item.name" v-tooltip="{show: !item.pagerId, content:item.email item.phone item.specialtu,placement: \'top\'}"><dt>{{item.label}}</dt><dd style="margin-bottom:0.25rem;">' +
    }
);

I would like the popup to show this (on 3 seperate lines):
Email: myemail@gmail.com
Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxxx
Specialty: my specialty

Can I define a v-tooltip differently where I can use a block of html codes?
Much appreciated.

Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267687/how-to-add-a-newline-in-vuetify-v-tooltip

What installed package/library provides the v-tooltip directive?

@Shaya Ulman: I am using v.tooltip.min.js

What is the source library? You must know that in order to be able to look up the docs.

I believe it is from https://github.com/Morioh-Lab/v-tooltip.
It said:  content: 'Html content '

I tried this:
content:\'Email:{{ item.email }}<br>Phone: {{ item.phone }}<br>Specialty: {{  item.specialty }}\'
but the item.email, item.phone and item.specialty are not resolved into the actual values.

Finally, I was able to resolve this issue by adding a methods to the existing component  like this:
 methods: { createTooltipHtmlContent: createTooltipHtmlContent }
This method is used to generate the html content for the Content of the tooltip like this:
v-tooltip.top="{show: !item.pagerId, content:createTooltipHtmlContent(item)}

Finally, I was able to resolve this issue by adding a function to the methods section of the component like this:
methods: { createTooltipHtmlContent: createTooltipHtmlContent }
This method is used to generate the html content for the Content of the tooltip and the v-tooltip after is like this: v-tooltip.top="{show: !item.pagerId, content:createTooltipHtmlContent(item)}
